# ¿Cómo puedo instalar la versión 5 de Angular CLI (Si ya tengo la versión 6)?

Tags: angular

He tenido problemas con la nueva versión y quiero instalar la versión anterior.
¿Alguien conoce el comando?

Comment: Que es lo que quieres, Angular 5 O la version anterior del CLI, por que angular cli no tiene una version 5 hasta donde tengo entendido, antes de la version 6 esta llegaba a la 1.7.4 y al parecer quicieron homogar la nueva version de angular con el CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para hacer un `downgrade`

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1
```

Puede que por la versión de npm tengas que llamarlo asi:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1
```

el `@1` te instala la última versión para Angular 5 (1.7.4)

Hay una forma de usar ambos cli muy bien explicada en https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-5-or-angular-6-yes-please-d71b08b5e59b

(Traducción libre y resumida)

Para ir cambiando según el proyecto:

Crear proyecto Angular 5

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1
ng new proyecto-Angular5
```

Crear proyecto Angular 6

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6
ng new proyecto-Angular6
```

Para tener ambas versiones:

1 - instalar cli 6 global

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6
```

2 - crear una carpeta para los proyectos Angular 5

```
mkdir ng5
cd ng5
```

3 - en esta carpeta crear una aplicación npm local

```
npm init -y
```

4 - instalar cli 5 localmente

```
npm install @angular/cli@1
```

5 - borrar el archivo `package.json` para que al hacer `ng new` no proteste, si no se borra este archivo ng asume que estas creando una nueva app dentro de una app existente.

6 - crear la nueva app angular 5

```
ng new proyecto-Angular5
```

Desde este momento todos los `ng new` que crees dentro de la carpeta `ng5` van a ser angular 5, crear un app en otro lado tomará el cli global (angular 6)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar.