# Versiones específicas para Angular 2 y 4

Tags: angular

Entré al Github de Angular Cli con la intención de buscar la última versión de Angular en sus versiones `2 y 4`. Encontré que para Angular 5, la última versión es: `1.7.4`, sin embargo, para instalar dicha versión en un proyecto independiente (Proyecto local, el cual es mi propósito de fondo) es necesario hacer la instalación de la forma `npm install @angular/cli@1`.

Quería saber cómo hago para instalar la última versión tanto para la versión 2 como la versión 4?

Comment: posiblemente relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/188216/81450

Comment: No lo es, precisamente de ahí saqué como instalar la versión 5, pero aquí solicito las versiones 2 y 4.

Comment: yo lo veo relacionado pues a partir de la versión 6 el cli acomoda el major, onda `npm install -g @angular/cli@6` repecto a cada sub versión habría que ver el repo (filtras por tags) y vas probando con el método "por carpeta" que se explica en la traducción de tener 5 y 6 a la vez

Comment: Claro, fui probando carpeta por carpeta, es por eso que ya di la respuesta sobre cómo instalar cada versión, como proyectos locales. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una respuesta un poco extraña a mi interrogante y la comparto con ustedes.

Instalar la versión 2:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.33.1
```

Esto me instala la versión 2.4.0

Instalar la versión 4:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.4
```

Esto me instala la versión 4.2.4

Instalar la versión 5:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1
```

Supongo que de momento el @1 representa a la versión 5, posiblemente esto cambie con la versión 7 de angular y tendríamos que usar `@angular/cli@1.5` o algo similar.

Lo que no puedo confirmar es que son efectivamente las últimas versiones liberadas de cada versión de este framework. Si alguien lo confirma sería genial.